# How to start jquery countdown from datepicker form input?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web

I'm building a simple webpage for wedding event. Let's say that I need to show a countdown and I want to get the date to start it from an input form. I've been googling a lot and I've seen some interesting code but it's late and my eyes and mind are very tired. This is my code...

```
<?php $date = date('2017/05/21'); // this value supossed to be taken from a form.?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="clock"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.testingserver.dev/template/assets/web/assets/jquery/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<script>
var eventdate = new Date("<?php echo $date; ?>"); // I'm trying to use a php variable in jquery.
$('#clock').countdown('eventdate', function(event) {
var $this = $(this).html(event.strftime(''
//+ '<div style="background-color: #ffcc00; width: 25%;"><p>Weeks<br>%w</p></div> '
+ '<span>%D</span> days '
+ '<span>%H</span> hrs '
+ '<span>%M</span> min '
+ '<span>%S</span> sec'));
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is `'207/05/21'` a copy/paste error? Or do you really have `207` as your year value?

Comment: Also, I don't think there is a `countdown` in jQuery UI, so what is the source of this function? Is there a reason that `'eventdate'` is in quotes, as a string, and not without as a K's var?

Comment: is a copy/paste error, the sample date is 2017/05/21, but it supossed to get this value dinamically. Thaks for noticing it, @Sean

Comment: No, there's no a countdown there, but is some other plugin. [link](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) and what I'm trying to do is use both. @Sean

Comment: And... how I am do that? (K's var). I need you to guide through. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is link to the library website - http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

You're passing string `'eventdate'` to the `countdown()` method but it expects to be a valid date. So just remove the apostrophes and you'll get the `eventdate` variable's value:

```
$('#clock').countdown(eventdate, function(event) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Did it and it's working. Thanks man! Now I can go to sleep. @PetrHejda